# 'cfx' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was actually developing an add-on with the Add-on Builder but now I would like to change to SDK since there are more possibilities.
I have installed the sdk and Python like so: 
C:\Users\bla\Add-ons\addon-sdk-1.8.1
(inside addon-sdk-1.8.1 I added the tar Python-2.6.8)
Now in the cmd I typed:

```
cd C:\Users\bla\Add-ons\addon-sdk-1.8.1  
mkdir my-addon  
cd my-addon  
cfx init
```

That worked fine -> the folder my-addon has been created with the whole directory in it.
Then I deleted the folder my-addon and tried the same commands again and got:

```
'cfx' is not recognized as internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

`mddir my-addon` created the folder my-addon. But `cfx init` produced the error.

It's the first time I'm working with cmd commands and I have no clue what I gotta do now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to activate the sdk's environment first, please see the installation docs:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html

Essentially, you need to run the command

bin/activate

...from the root directory of the SDK. There are additional docs on the above link if you want to make the environment always available in your shell.

Comment: Thank's lot, bin\activate was all I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

windows users run:

> source bin/activate

and it should add (addon-sdk-1.XX) to the end of the welcome message.